# Can I run these nested queries as one query, and how do I work with the returned information?

Tags: mysql

I've never used MySQL for anything involving many tables; when I have, I've nested queries to get the information that I need.

A good example I can think of when I want to output some blog `posts` and their related `comments`.

The tables could look like this (simplified to keep the question short):

> **posts:**           `id | title | content`
>   **comments:**   `id | post_id | author | content`

Where `comments.post_id` is obviously linked to the relevant `post.id`.

I'd then output the posts and the comments like this (I'd normally expand the query a little more, but again want to keep the question short):

```php
// Get posts.
$posts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC");

while($prow = mysql_fetch_assoc($posts))
{
    $pid = $prow["id"];

    // Write post.
    echo '
        <h2 id="post' . $pid . '">' . $prow["title"] . '</h2>
        <p>' . $prow["content"] . '</p>';



    // Get related comments.
    $cquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = '$pid' ORDER BY id DESC");

    while($crow = mysql_fetch_assoc($cquery))
    {
        $cid = $crow["id"];

        // Write comment.
        echo '<p id="comment' . $cid . '"><strong>' . $crow["author"] . ':</strong> ' . $crow["content"] . '</p>';
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, this would mean that if I had 10 blog posts, there would be 11 queries (1 for the posts and then an additional query for the comments for each post). That doesn't seem sane.

I'm sure there's a way to create a query that will select the posts as well as the relevant comments all-in-one, I just have no idea what the correct way to do that is. I've vaguely heard about joins, but when I read about them, they aren't making much sense to me.

It would be nice to end up with something roughly like:

```
$query = mysql_query("
    SELECT
        posts.id,
        posts.title,
        posts.content,
        comments.id,
        comments.author,
        comments.content
    FROM
        posts,
        comments
    WHERE
        comments.post_id = post.id,
");
```

And then I could just do something like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo '
        <h2 id="post' . $row["posts.id"] . '">' . $row["posts.title"] . '</h2>
        <p>' . $row["posts.content"] . '</p>';

    // Somehow iterate over the comments and display them.
    //
}
```

I hope I explained what I want to achieve properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your way would work (at least it would in MS SQL), but the standard way would be to use a join:

```
SELECT
    posts.id AS post_id,
    posts.title,
    posts.content,
    comments.id AS comment_id,
    comments.author,
    comments.content
FROM posts
INNER JOIN comments ON comments.post_id = post.id
ORDER BY post_id, comment_id DESC
```

Comment: How do I output those comments in my while loop? This is where it gets confusing for me, does `$row` in my latter sample contain an array with these comments that I can loop through?

Comment: @MartyWallace yes, exactly.  Since it's a one-to-many join, the post fields will be duplicated over multiple rows, but that's ok.

Comment: I'll play around with `var_dump` and see what I get. Also I just had a thought; how can I sort the posts in ASCENDING order but the comments in DESCENDING order? Is that something I can do in the query or do I need to do that myself afterwards?

Comment: That's no problem.  You can sort by two columns.  See update above.

Comment: Ah right, I didn't notice that; yes, alias the columns.  You might also be able to access them from PHP as "posts.content" and "comments.content", but I'm not sure how PHP handles that scenario.

Comment: I just worked out that's what `AS` is for :) (forgot that part). So how does one generally deal with the multiple rows containing the same blog post? Just skip the part that writes it to the page if it's the same as the last post?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9981/discussion-between-dbaseman-and-marty-wallace)